# List of Json Processing from a InputSteam continue on error too

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, jsonparser

I have a list of json object coming in from AWS input stream. 
Each json objects are specific custom/user objects.

I need help as I'm stuck in point 2.

1. picks json object-->converts to custom Object.
2. If the conversion fails with any parse exception of json, then the code should log/print in the console the error'd out a record. continue to next json record.

I have the object-mapper/JsonParser(from Jackson Library) to do the conversion using `readValueAs()` method.

I'm stuck in the second part to fetch the error'd out the record and log it. then continue with next record.

Examples are below

```
{
    "col1":"col1Value",
    "col2":"col2Value",
    "col3":"col3Value", 
    {sub-json-objects}**,**
    "col4":"col4Value"
}

{
    "col11":"col11Value",
    "col12":"col12Value",
    "col13":"col13Value", 
    {sub-json-objects}***(supposingly if the comma is missing here)***
    "col14":"col14Value"
}
```

i.e.

```
{
    "col11":"col11Value",
    "col12":"col12Value",
    "col13":"col13Value", {sub-json-objects}
    "col14":"col14Value"
}
```

If you guys can suggest me any other approach its fine. I'm looking for error'd out json + log and continue it further.

I tried below

```
@Override
    public T next() {
        try {

            return (T) jp.readValueAs((Class<T>) type);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Failed Record --> " + jp.currentToken());
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Regards,
Pawan.

Comment: *need java8 code which does below.* wouldn't work here. Try something and come back in case it doesn't work, please.

Comment: I've tried using jp.currentToken(); it returns me NULL. so I'm stuck !

Comment: In that case, share what you've tried and which part didn't work in it.

Comment: Tried this. but doesnt work
@Override
    public T next() {
     Object obj=null;
     try {
   
         return (T) jp.readValueAs((Class<T>) type);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

         logger.info("Failed Record --> " + jp.currentToken());
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: In the question please. Comments might get lost as the discussion progress.

Comment: edited. pls look over.